# How to create category in magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$rootCatNode = $data['catalog'][0];
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();
$rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$cat_info = $rootCat->load($rootCatNode);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($data['catalognew'] as  $newdata){
    $getCatData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($newdata);
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    //  if($getCatData->getLevel()==2) {
    $categoryTmp = $categoryFactory->create();
    $categoryTmp->setName($getCatData->getName());
    $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
    $categoryTmp->setUrlKey(rand(0, 999));
    $categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
    $categoryTmp->setParentId($getCatData->getParentId());
    $getCatDatan = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($getCatData->getParentId());
    $categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
    $categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
    echo $getCatDatan->getPath();
    echo "<br>";
    echo $rootCat->getPath();
    $categoryTmp->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="catalognew">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Categories For Duplicate</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
                <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Code:

```
function createCategory($a='',$b=2,$c=true,$d='',$e='',$f='',$g='') {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create();
        $category->setName($a); //category name
        $category->setParentId($b); // 1: root category.
        $category->setIsActive($c); // for active true and inactive false
        $category->setCustomAttributes([
'description' => $d,  
'meta_title' => $e,
'meta_keywords' => $f,
 'meta_description' => $g,
     ]);
        $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface')->save($category);
}
createCategory("Abc");
createCategory("Xyz",4,false,"description","m title");
```